# object 'new DataColumn()' is not disposed along all exception paths.

Tags: c#

I am dynamically adding column to datatable. 
For example,

`dtLayer.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "RowId", DataType =    typeof(string), ReadOnly = true })}`

During compiling I am getting the following code warning

`object 'new DataColumn()' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new DataColumn()' before all references to it are out of scope.`

Included the code in `using` block, but still the warning persist.

Do let me know any other better way of implementing

Comment: can you post full code including dtLayer datatable as well ?

Comment: I'd especially like to see your using statement.